# Use 2 different server for send and receive email

Tags: dns, cloudflare, mail-server

I have a classified website in a VPS. VPS are configured only like Web & MySQL server. I actually use an external mail provider for send mail from cms used in website to users. I have configured DNS on Cloudflare like follow:

```
domain-name.xxx in A [WEB SERVER IP]
ftp in CNAME domain-name.com
www in CNAME domain-name.com
domain-name.xxx in MX mail.provider.host priority 10
domain-name.xxx in MX mail2.provider.host priority 20
domain-name.xxx in TXT "v=spf1 include:spf-c.mail.provider.host mx a ~all"
```

Now i want use only noreply@domain-name.xxx (large number of emails are sent from this email address) with Dedicated mail hosting provider (it's not cheap but is affordable) and I want to use info@domain-name.xxx, or personal email accounts like name.surname@domain-name.xxx on another hosting provider ( cheap :-) ).

I'd like know if is correct adding follow DNS rules for use a second server (for info@ etc):

```
domain-name.xxx in MX new.mail.host priority 10
```

I don't know if i must add any other rule.

Comment: This has really nothing at all do with programming and therefore it totally **off-topic** here - please post to a more relevant site, like serverfault.com or somewhere else

Comment: ... But NO, you can not divide the receiving of emails for one domain across multiple email servers. You need no dns settings for sending from multiple servers though

Comment: First thing you should do is changing `~all` to `-all`. It's not the answer to your question but something you definetly wanna do.

Answer (score 2):

If the mail you are sending from your server is no-reply then you could:

- use a service like [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com) . It's ideal for transactional email, and very affordable. Since the website email is outgoing only, the only DNS entries you'll need are 2 SPF & DKIM records, no MX required
- then in CloudFlare add just the MX for your info@ and personal mail server
- and finally configure your email to bounce anything to noreply@

If this would fit your business setup then it's easy and may well cost less than using a dedicated server for sending outgoing website email.

If you needed more options for the outgoing website email, Mailgun also let's you setup a subdomain like “mg.mydomain.com”. Using a subdomain you will still be able to send emails from your root domain e.g. “noreply@mydomain.com” and it will play well with your personal email.

Good luck!